# Validate many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

posts 1--* post_tags *--1 tags

A post has many tags and a tag has many posts. They are related through the post_tags table.

```
post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accressible :tag_ids

  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags
end

tag.rb
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags
end

post_tag.rb
class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_To :tag
end

posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.save ? redirect_to(:action => 'index') : render(:action => 'new')
  end
end
```

The tags table is a catalog and I just want the user to select the appropriate ones for the post.
So in my view I have a multiple select:

```
new.html.erb
post_form.collection_select(:tag_ids, @tags, nil, nil, {}, { :multiple => true })
```

This works but the problem is when I send invalid ids I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Posts#create
Couldn't find all Tags with IDs (1, 200) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Tag with id 1 exists but tag with id 200 doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got your problem, when you send in some invalid tag_id say, 200 the Rails will first search whether the Tag with ID 200 actually exist or not. So the best way to tackle this problem is to use a before filter where you make sure that you get the correct or valid ids. And then you can simply do an assignment which would assign the tag_ids to the post....You can do something like this

```
before_filter :find_tags_from_ids

def find_tags_from_ids
  @tags = Tag.where(:id => params[:post][:tag_ids]
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.tags << @tags
  @post.save ? redirect_to(:action => 'index') : render(:action => 'new')
end
```

This would solve your problem and hopefully you won't get an exception this time..

Comment: The intermediate post_tags table would automatically be updated when you save the post object..

Comment: And how do I catch the error? I would like to have it in the errors array

Comment: The errors array is for the validations but if you want to use errors array in this then you can do this by adding the error message to the errors message and then returning false from the before_filter. You can also redirect from the before_filter if you find any errors there.